# Login Failed: com.google.android.gms.common.api.b: 10:

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I made a App in Flutter for Android and used Firebase google login. It worked well on the web, and Android Studio phone simulator. But when I uploaded it to play store console and downloaded on my phone and tried to login, a error like the following comes up. What is the problem and how do I fix it.

I thought it was a version problem so I tried updating it. Also I put it all the libraries needed as well.

Comment: Unless you have more information that indicates otherwise, the best we can do is link you do other questions that came up about this error message: https://www.google.com/search?q=Login+Failed%3A+com.google.android.gms.common.api.b%3A+10%3A